# Reaction between tubli root and jatropha leaf

Tags: biochemistry

What compounds are found in [tubli root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derris_elliptica) and [jatropha leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatropha) extracts?

Would they react if they were mixed together?

Answer (score 3):

Tubli roots (*Derris elliptica*) contain **rotenone** (**1**), a furocoumarin.

[image: rotenone]

Rotenone that has been used as an insecticide, and in the U.S., it is an EPA-approved fish toxicant. According to an [article it SFGate](http://www.sfgate.com/bayarea/article/Workers-pour-poison-into-Mountain-Lake-begin-5888355.php), it has been used in 2014 to completely kill the remaining fish population after a lake became infested with alien species.

*Jatropha* are known to contain differents toxins, such as derivatives of **phorbol**, a highly substituted tetracyclic azulene diterpenoid, and toxic proteins. It is worth to be mentioned that phorbol esters are known to promote tumor activity.

You might find further details in the following review, *J. Toxicol. Environ. Health B Crit. Rev.* **2010** ,*13*, 476-507, and there are numerous other articles on the toxicology of both compounds.

However, I'm not aware of studies that examined possible reactions **between** these compounds.